# Do Buggers go to heaven?

Tags: enders-game, religion, orson-scott-card

Orson Scott Card is a Mormon.

Has he ever explained the status of Formics/Buggers in terms of having souls, going to heaven/hell, or any other aspect of how they fit into his religion?

Comment: You are aware that the bugs aren't actually real?

Comment: @Richard The books got pretty theological. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a canon answer available.

Comment: If all dogs go to heaven then why the hell no?

Comment: @JeremyBanks - the books are a **story about humans**. Humans are inherently religious, thus theological bent. The books are not theological from a theology point of view, outside of storytelling.

Comment: @DVK Enter's Game is a book about humans, but Children of the Mind is as much about fun abstract metaphysical speculation as anything else. It's not a representation of Card's personal theology, but it does start building an internal framework within which questions like this can be discussed directly. (I'll drop this thread now.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - OSC was **very very** explicit that the "abstract metaphysical speculation" was just storytelling. Philotes and such was a **storytelling device**, not some deep Mormon metaphor.

Comment: @Richard - *To fight the bug, we must understand the bug*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OSC has said on [his website](http://hatrack.com/research/questions/q0110.shtml):

> Any analogies to Mormon ideas in the Ender books are entirely unconscious and unintended. When I do such things deliberately - as a sort of wink to those who get the joke - it's very obvious and needs no confirmation from me.

That said, we do find one statement from *Ender's Game* which may shed light on what (if any) religious beliefs the buggers themselves had:

> If  only  we  could  have  talked  to you. But  since  it  could  not  be,  we ask only  this:  that  you  remember us,  not  as  enemies,  but  as  tragic sisters,  changed  into  a  foul  shape by  Fate  or God  or  Evolution.
>
> --Hive Queen (*Ender's Game, Chapter 15, "Speaker for the Dead"*)

Answer (score 8):

@ibid already gave an excellent [out-of-universe answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110614/976).

In-universe - at least, before the Children of the Mind timeline - the closest we have to a genuine theology expert<sup>[1]</sup> is Sister Carlotta. Let's ask **her**.

Oops - too late. <strike>The Fastest Gun in the West strikes again</strike>.

<strike>Colonel</strike> Mr. Graff already did, before I could ask:

> "I just don't understand why they have to find a scapegoat for victory."
>
> "I'll be fine. The sun still shines on planet Earth."
>
> "But never again on their tragic world."
>
> "Is your God also their God, Sister Carlotta? Did he take them into heaven?"
>
> **"He's not my God, Mr. Graff. But I am his child, as are you. I don't know whether he looks at the Formics and sees them, too, as his children."**
>
> (*Ender's Shadow, Chapter 24, "Homecoming"*)

There you have it. In-universe expert's definitive answer is **I don't know**.

<sub>[1] - I'll leave aside John Paul's and Zeck's fathers, neither of which are worth listening to despite being self-proclaimed experts on their religion.</sub>

---

**UPDATE**:

If you include "Children of the Mind" trilogy, the answer changes.

The experts there - notably, the Bishop on Lusitania - fully believed that they could convert *raman* pequeninos to Christianity, and therefore that they have souls capable of going to heaven.

As such, buggers - who by then have also been considered *raman*, in the wake of The Speaker and Demosthenes's work - would presumably also be just as capable of entering heaven.

However, this requires two caveats:

- First, a technical Christian caveat. **One does NOT simply walk into <strike>Mordor</strike> heaven**. You need to be:

  1. Baptized.

     - With a small caveat that Mormons/LDS believe that you can be baptized after you're dead. Details [here](http://religion.blogs.cnn.com/2012/02/16/explainer-how-and-why-do-mormons-baptize-the-dead/) and on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptism_for_the_dead#The_Church_of_Jesus_Christ_of_Latter-day_Saints)
  2. Saved, in a specific religious ritual, consciously, by accepting Jesus as your savior.

     - Please note that this applies 100% universally, meaning even those who supposedly were baptised after death in an LDS manner aren't automatically saved - merely given a chance to choose to be saved.
- Second, an in-universe caveat. It's entirely unclear if **individual buggers** can have souls and enter heaven, or only the Queens. I think it's the former but that's definitely NOT covered in canon.

Please note that to research this, I have searched entire text of all Ender books for "heaven", "soul" and "saved".

Comment: For transparency's sake: there are other theology experts in the series if you include Children of the Mind trilogy. On one hand, ones on deliberately-false religion on Path. On another hand, Lusitania has a Bishop and monks

Comment: Upvote from me... good answer!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To a couple notes ... Just to throw out a wild guess, I'd bet that missionaries would treat a queen and all her drones as one organism, because that's how they see themselves.  Unless they find out from Bean about how the males have individual consciousness until the Q's beat them down... creepy!